# Why cannot I invoke nonstatic methods as this argument in constructor?

Tags: java, methods, constructor, instance

### valid code 1:

```
class ClassForTest{
    ClassForTest(int k){         
    };
    ClassForTest(){
         this(2);
         method();
    };
    int method(){return 1;}     
}
```

my resolution - I can invoke non static method in constructor!

### non valid code

```
class ClassForTest{
    ClassForTest(int k){
    };
    ClassForTest(){
         this(method());
    };
    int method(){return 1;}
}
```

compile error:

```
java: cannot reference this before supertype constructor has been called
```

### valid code 2:

```
class ClassForTest{
    ClassForTest(int k){
    };
    ClassForTest(){
         this(method());  
    };
    static int method(){return 1;}
}
```

### valid code 3:

```
class ClassForTest{
    ClassForTest(int k){
    };
    {
        method();
    }
    ClassForTest(){
         this(1);
    };
    int method(){return 1;}
}
```

This behavior set is strange for me.

Can you explain it in common ?

### update

As  I understand compiler merges init blocks following:

```
constructor(){
   super();
   nonStaticInitBlock;
   remain constructor code;
}
```

I don't see contradictions why I cannot use this invokation as argument of constructor

### EDIT

Instance initializers are invoked after the last constructor call. –  Sotirios Delimanolis Jun 1 at 17:17

@Sotirios you are wrong

research this code:

```
public class Order {
    { 
        System.out.println("initializer!");
    } 
    Order(){ 
        System.out.println("constructor");
    } 
    public static void main(String [] args){
        new Order(); 
    }
}
```

result:

```
initializer!
constructor
```

Comment: in duplicated question didn't explain **valid code 3**

Comment: Instance initializers are invoked after the last constructor call.

Comment: public class Order {
    {public class Order {
    {
        System.out.println("initializer!");
    }
    Order(){
        System.out.println("constructor");
    }
    public static void main(String [] args){
        new Order();
    }
}
        System.out.println("initializer!");
    }
    Order(){
        System.out.println("constructor");
    }
    public static void main(String [] args){
        new Order();
    }
}

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis you are wrong

Comment: I can refer to this pointer in initialization block. This block executes before constructor thus object is not designed but I can invoke it.

Comment: Please don't put code in comments. Edit it in to your question. When you do that, your question is re-added to the re-open queue where people can vote to re-open it.

Comment: I have understood right answer but I cannot answer.

Comment: When I say _last constructor call_, I mean the last `this()` invocation in constructor chaining. You would have something like `cons1 -> cons2 -> instance initializers -> cons3` assuming `cons1` called `this(..)` referring to `cons2` and `cons2` called `this(..)` referring to `cons3`.

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis I agree now but ut was ambiguous

Answer (score 1):

(Changed because earlier answer wasn't right)

I believe the answer lies in the error the compiler gave you:

```
java: cannot reference this before supertype constructor has been called
                                   ^^^^^^^^^
```

Looking at JLS Section 12.5:

> If this constructor begins with an explicit constructor invocation (§8.8.7.1) of another constructor in the same class (using `this`), then evaluate the arguments and process that constructor invocation recursively using these same five steps.

And in JLS 8.8.7:

> An explicit constructor invocation statement in a constructor body may not refer to any instance variables or instance methods or inner classes declared in this class or any superclass, or use this or super in any expression; otherwise, a compile- time error occurs.

So in order to run the code in your second listing, `method()` needs to be evaluated before going into the body of `this()`. However, the spec forbids this, because the object's state may not have been fully initialized, e.g. for a subclass of a type whose constructor sets some state inherited by the subtype.

Comment: what about **valid code 3** ?

Comment: @gstackoverflow Initialization blocks run *after* `this()` and/or `super()` is called, so that block is OK

Comment: hm, interesting order!

Comment: @gstackoverflow If you want to learn more, check out sections 12.4 and 12.5 of the JLS, where the exact steps for initializing classes, interfaces, and objects is specified.

Comment: I know that this order is right but it is enough messed order.

Comment: **initialization blocks run after this()** you are wrong

Comment: @gstackoverflow Yeah, after rereading the spec I have to agree that I made a mistake there. In fact, I think that my answer as stated isn't right. I'll have a fix up shortly.

Answer (score 0):

```
class ClassForTest{
    ClassForTest(int k){
    };
    ClassForTest(){
         this(method());
    };
    int method(){return 1;}
}
```

Now `method()` is an instance method meaning it needs to be called on an Object of type ClassForTest. Above code essentially means

```
ClassForTest(){
             this(this.method());
        };
```

and you cannot call this.something()  in the constructor as the Object is not created until all the constructors of super class are invoked. So this is not allowed.

Where as in case of static method you do not have to wait till Object creating i.e calling of all superclass constructors. So it is allowed.

Comment: what about valid code 3 ?  there method invokation happens before constructor invocation!!!!